# Icones não aparecem corretamente

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, webdesign

Galera, estou atualizando um site, e os ícones da tela inicial não estão aparecendo.

Apenas aparecem se eu for pra outra página e depois voltar para inicial.

o site é: [www.artbordados.com.br](http://www.artbordados.com.br)

No console do navegador, aparece o seguinte erro:

> Font from origin 'http://www.artbordados.com.br' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://artbordados.com.br' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Segundo esta resposta do Stackoverflow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource

o problema é que vc está usando requisições ajax para carregar recursos de um site diferente do seu servidor e isso só é permitido através de extensões como o CORS.

Aqui tem uma solução que vc pode aplicar facilmente:

http://loiane.com/2014/01/requests-ajax-com-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-entre-sencha-touch-e-extjs-e-backend/

acredito que esta extensão do Wordpress tbém pode ser útil:

https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cors/